# Clip the vertical and horizontal overflow of <pre> tag outside of its container, and show scrollbars

Tags: css, html

I have a div with a specific size (300px by 300px). Inside the div is a `pre` tag with a snippet of source code. The snippet can be of an arbitrary size. I'm trying to style the `div` and the `pre` tag so that the source code does not wrap horizontally unless there is a line break. And if there is overflow, it should not be visible, and scroll bars should be displayed. This should work for both horizontal and vertical overflow.

So far I have a vertical scroll bar, but the text gets wrapped horizontally. Here is the css (mostly copied from StackOverflow's code formatting):

```
pre {
    max-height: none\9;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: Consolas, Monaco;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
    text-overflow: clip;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

And here an example of the html:

```
<div class="item" data-handle=".snippetHeader">

<h5 class="snippetHeader">Snippet7</h5>

<div class="code">
    <pre>
        <code>

DWORD WINAPI ValueFunc(LPVOID arg){
    //printf(&quot;Thread Created\n&quot;);
    x = (i + .5)*step;
    sum = sum + 4.0 / (1. + x*x);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    clock_t start, stop;
    step = 1. / (double)num_steps;
    start = clock();

    HANDLE hThread[num_steps];
    for (i = 0; i&lt;num_steps; i++) {         

        hThread[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ValueFunc, NULL, 0, NULL);

    }

    WaitForMultipleObjects(num_steps, hThread, TRUE, INFINITE);

    pi = sum*step;
    stop = clock();
    printf(&quot;The value of PI is %15.12f\n&quot;, pi);
    printf(&quot;The time to calculate PI was %f seconds\n&quot;, ((double)(stop - start) / 1000.0));

}
        </code>
    </pre>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

I include Bootstrap css in this page. If I comment it out, the text is displayed how I want. Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y29AM/
If you remove the 2 external resources that are specified there you'll see the difference. Any idea what in Bootstrap needs to be overriden to make it work?

Comment: What browser are you using? It looks fine in Chrome and Firefox on OS X.

Comment: I'm using IE 11 on Windows. But it also doesn't look OK in Chrome on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following to `pre` css:

```
pre {
    ...
    white-space: pre;
    word-wrap: normal;
}
```

And also added this css:

```
pre code {
    white-space: inherit;
}
```

Now it's not wrapping horizontally and works like I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

```
white-space: nowrap
```

Turn word wrapping off.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The line `hThread[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ValueFunc, NULL, 0, NULL);` still gets wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```css
pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```